# DB2 delete statement error when row not present

Tags: sql, db2, error-code

Folks,
In DB2 9.x, delete statement works normally and gives successful return code if the particular row is present. But if the row is not present, it returns non-zero

ie  Say EmployeeTable  doesn't contain employeeID 1234
`db2 "delete from EmployeeTable where employeeID = 1234"`
 It gives output as below.

```
SQL0100W  No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of a query is an empty table.  SQLSTATE=02000
```

Is there anyway to return a success/zero return code, if there are no rows present?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Bruno: We have been provided a external wrapper script, to input SQL's. But the wrapper script always checks if the return code of the SQL is Zero. Hence a bug has been raised to us to handle the empty value scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap that delete statement in a **stored procedure**, and catch the exception inside. The stored procedure execution will always throw 0.

From the command line, there is nothing you can do, because the command has a warning. You can also do a post process when calling the db2 delete, for example, create a **shell function**, and change the error code if that sqlcode was raised.

Comment: thanks @AngocA. Is there a way using decode or similar kind to capture the empty row condition?

Comment: Something like a decode could be done in a stored procedure: create procedure p () begin declare dummy int ; declare continue handler for sqlstate '02000' set dummy = 1 ; delete from tableX; end@

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is not uncommon when forced to use another program to execute your SQL code.

The following is a bad idea, but will work if you are the only user of the table.

If you have insert privileges, you can insert a dummy row and follow that command with an delete that will include the dummy row.  That way the delete always gets at least one row:

```sql
    insert into mytable (id) values (9999999);

    delete from mytable
    where date_of_job >= current date - 1 day or
    id=9999999;
```